# How to use extension methods with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, azure

I need to use two extension methods SqlCommandExtensions & SqlConnectionExtensions

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.windowsazure.transientfaulthandling.sqlazure(v=pandp.50).aspx

Here they say the I have to use these if I use entity framework http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680906%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx

> In addition, the SqlCommandExtensions and SqlConnectionExtensions classes provide a set of extension methods that enable .NET developers to open SQL Azure database connections and invoke the SQL commands. These extension methods are useful in the event that you are unable to adapt your code to take advantage of the ReliableSqlConnection class. For example, you may be using the Enterprise Library Data Access Application Block or **Entity Framework** that use SqlConnection instances internally.

The problem is that they don't provide any example on how to use this.
How exactly do I use these extension methods with Entity Framework? Should I use inheritance or/and where exactly should it be done?

Comment: Which class in entity framework do you wish to extend?

Comment: Just curious: why would you use these pretty low-level methods in combination with a component that handles connections and commands as transparently as possible?

Comment: If your using VS you will see all extension methods is indicated with a blueish down arrow as icon, work with the intellisense and look at the method signatures, sure you will figure out some kind of working code

Comment: jacqijvv I use all EF with model. I need that EF uses ReliableSqlConnection instead of SqlConnection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you just need to make sure to look in the right place. [Here are the list of SqlCommandExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.windowsazure.transientfaulthandling.sqlazure.sqlcommandextensions_methods%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) and [here are the list of SqlConnectionExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.windowsazure.transientfaulthandling.sqlazure.sqlconnectionextensions_methods%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx). I think they actually are fairly self-explanatory on how each should be used. You could probably google for an example of each one.

However, these seem pretty low-level compared to the POCO ORM way that you should probably use:

[DbContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) and [ObjectContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext_methods.aspx) methods that you can use with POCOs

Comment: I don't understand your answer, but I will try to simplify my question.
I have an Azure MVC project which is uses EF model to access SQL Azure.
I need to integrate Transient Fault handling application block and for this they say that I need to use the extension methods, but how?